# SharePoint web part custom EditorPart hide for non-admin users

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have a SharePoint web part that exposes a set of configurable properties - since they have the PersonalizationScope property set to Shared, when a non-admin user edits the webpart settings they do not show up.

There is also a custom property, for which I've implemented a custom EditorPart. How can I hide the my EditorPart from the settings section when the user that modifies the web part is not an admin.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the IWebEditable interface, you can add your custom EditorPart to the EditorPartCollection, only if the current user is in the Admin role.

Good luck with it,

Calin :)